# Is single-window mode possible in Console2?

Tags: window, console2

I recently discovered Console2, and I love it.  I was wondering... if console.exe is invoked a second time, can it be configured to put its tab in the first window?  In my case, I have a scheduled task that always opens a new window.  I'd rather have it open a new tab in the existing console.exe window instead.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Original Console2 - can't do that you want.

You may try to switch to its fork by [Kirill](http://kirill.ca/dblog/storico.asp?s=Console), there is `-reuse` switch.

Or, you may switch to [ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) - another free terminal emulator (I'm the author). It may be configured as "single instance" in settings, or you may use `/single` switch with ConEmu.exe. Also, you may create new tab from existing tab using [-new_console](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole) switch. E.g. type in cmd prompt `putty -new_console` and it will starts in new ConEmu's tab.